# QGIS equivalent to FME Change Detector for vector data

Tags: qgis, fme-form

Is there a **Vector** change detection tool for qgis that works similar to http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/changedetector.htm

It's OK if there's two tools -one spatial and one attributional. Before I go down the line of trying to create one? I have searched online and in the plugins but can't find anything.

- **Spatial change -** has the boundary changed at all, example a parcel split or merged, a new area added etc [image].
  I am mostly interested in polygon changes. Points and lines are easier to handle with existing spatial tools.
- **Attribute change -** ability to select the attributes to review and then see if there are changes for a given unique key between the 2 datasets. The output should be a table which has the old and new values next to each other (FME doesn't do this -it just has a port for all changes)

So
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QGIS 3.14 and above have an inbuilt "Detect Dataset Changes" algorithm in the toolbox which is designed as a drop-in replacement of the FME algorithm.

Comment: Thanks -that didn't come up when I searched online -it together with the SQL code in the following gives me what I need. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63446143/sql-code-to-detect-change-between-two-tables-without-knowing-the-attributes/63447229?noredirect=1#comment112194815_63447229